# Python Unexpected ZeroDivisionError for unsued dictionary operation

Tags: python, stack

```
from collections import deque
def postfixExpression(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        print(ex, stack)
        try:
            stack.append(int(ex))
        except ValueError:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            switcher = {
                "+" : a + b,
                "-" : a - b,
                "*" : a * b,
                "/" : int(a / b),
                "^" : a ** b,
            }
            if ex not in switcher.keys():
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
            else:
                stack.append(switcher.get(ex))
    return stack.pop()

expression = "2 3 7 - 7 + 9 7 2 + - * *"
print(f"\nResult {postfixExpression(expression)}")
```

Above is a Postfix Evaluation program in python. It's working for most case.

But when I used input `"2 3 7 - 7 + 9 7 2 + - * *"`, it's giving `ZeroDivisionError`, even thought I didn't use divide(`/`) in input.

Error message:

```
$ python temp/temp.py 
4 deque([])
6 deque([4])
* deque([4, 6])
2 deque([24])
1 deque([24, 2])
- deque([24, 2, 1])
+ deque([24, 1])
7 deque([25])
7 deque([25, 7])
+ deque([25, 7, 7])
7 deque([25, 14])
6 deque([25, 14, 7])
+ deque([25, 14, 7, 6])
* deque([25, 14, 13])
* deque([25, 182])
3 deque([4550])
7 deque([4550, 3])
- deque([4550, 3, 7])
7 deque([4550, -4])
+ deque([4550, -4, 7])
9 deque([4550, 3])
7 deque([4550, 3, 9])
2 deque([4550, 3, 9, 7])
+ deque([4550, 3, 9, 7, 2])
- deque([4550, 3, 9, 9])
* deque([4550, 3, 0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\temp.py", line 11, in postfixExpression
    stack.append(int(ex))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\temp.py", line 52, in main
    print(f"\nresult {postfixExpression(expression)}")
  File "C:\Users\...\temp.py", line 19, in postfixExpression
    "/" : int(a / b),
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

When I comment `"/" : int(a / b),` line in switcher dict it's giving expected answer i.e 0.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error (main) and how to solve it?

Comment: you're evaluating ALL POSSIBLE SCENARIOS for a and b. Instead of using the `switcher` dictionary to calculate everything, you should use it as a mapping of function pointers to give the the function that SHOULD be applied to a and b.

Comment: Situations like this require debugging your code to track down the cause of the problem. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) describes some fundamental techniques that you can use to do this. Even if you are familiar with debugging, these techniques are always good to review.

Comment: Got it @Code-Apprentice changed question, so hopefully its more clear now. And I tried my best to debug the issue, also found other way to solve it. I wanted to what the issue is and why it was coming for this method. Not everyone is on same level, it might basic debug for you, but many I don't think its for many early learns. I am getting error for the specific test case I mentioned and was not able to debug. That article doesn't provide any solution for the question, please don't discourage beginner programmer from asking doubts.

Comment: "it might basic debug for you, but many I don't think its for many early learns" I agree. Debugging is a learned skill just like anything else. And is as important as learning the syntax. This is why I provide the link. I prefer calling these skills "fundamental" rather than "basic". The techniques described in the article are the exact same things I would do to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are evaluating *all* of the operations at the time you set up your `switcher` dictionary. So regardless of which operator your code encounters, it calculates the sum, difference, product, and quotient of the two values at the top of the stack. Then it looks at the operator to decide which one to actually use. In this case, your `b` value is zero, so it is indeed trying to divide by zero.

There are a number of ways that you could fix this, including (but not limited to):

- use `lambda` functions in your `switcher` dictionary, and only call the one that is needed

```py
            switcher = {
                "+" : lambda: a + b,
                "-" : lambda: a - b,
                "*" : lambda: a * b,
                "/" : lambda: int(a / b),
                "^" : lambda: a ** b,
            }
            if ex not in switcher:
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
            else:
                stack.append(switcher[ex]())  # <- note the added () here
```

- just use a `match` statement to calculate the appropriate value directly in the code rather than using a dictionary (this requires Python 3.10+)

```py
    match ex:
        case "+":
            val = a + b
        case "-":
            val = a - b
        case "*":
            val = a * b
        case "/":
            val = int(a / b)
        case "^":
            val = a ** b
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
    stack.append(val)
```

- use an `if`-`elif` chain to calculate the appropriate value directly in the code rather than using a dictionary

```py
    if ex == "+":
        val = a + b
    elif ex == "-":
        val = a - b
    elif ex == "*":
        val = a * b
    elif ex == "/":
        val = int(a / b)
    elif ex == "^":
        val = a ** b
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
    stack.append(val)
```

In any case, I would recommend that you pull the calculation operation into a function of its own instead of having it embedded in the middle of your loop. Something like

```py
def calculate_value(op, a, b):
    ...  # Something based on what I've shown above


def postfixExpression(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        print(ex, stack)
        try:
            stack.append(int(ex))
        except ValueError:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            stack.append(calculate_value(ex, a, b))
    return stack.pop()
```

---

---

On request: the tested code using `lambda` functions:

```py
from collections import deque
def postfixExpression(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        print(ex, stack)
        try:
            stack.append(int(ex))
        except ValueError:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            switcher = {
                "+" : lambda: a + b,
                "-" : lambda: a - b,
                "*" : lambda: a * b,
                "/" : lambda: int(a / b),
                "^" : lambda: a ** b,
            }
            if ex not in switcher.keys():
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
            else:
                stack.append(switcher.get(ex)())
    return stack.pop()

expression = "2 3 7 - 7 + 9 7 2 + - * *"
print(f"\nResult {postfixExpression(expression)}")
```

with output

```
2 deque([])
3 deque([2])
7 deque([2, 3])
- deque([2, 3, 7])
7 deque([2, -4])
+ deque([2, -4, 7])
9 deque([2, 3])
7 deque([2, 3, 9])
2 deque([2, 3, 9, 7])
+ deque([2, 3, 9, 7, 2])
- deque([2, 3, 9, 9])
* deque([2, 3, 0])
* deque([2, 0])

Result 0
```

Comment: _"just use an actual `switch` statement"_ should that be `match`? Also, some small overhead can be saved by using [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) functions instead of `lambda`s

Comment: Yes, match, sorry. Will fix

Comment: I don't think overhead is of major concern to someone writing this code :-)

Comment: this ain't it chief, your lambda expression is wrong as it takes no input and you've managed to make the code 100x messier and funny enough less performance by using a match expression

Comment: The lambdas are fine (and tested) - they will capture the `a` and `b` values; the code may be a little longer now (depending on the option), but is certainly not 100x messier, my main intent was to keep the code as similar to what the asker had as possible; performance is so far from being a concern for code like this that it can't even be seen over the horizon

Comment: can you post the code that shows "lambdas are fine (and tested)"?

Comment: @lxop I'm not sure if you're a beginner or if you actually write messy, poorly scoped and poor-performing code on a daily basis to create a nightmare for others who have to work on projects after you do, but instead of insisting that "it works fine, I don't care", try to learn a thing or two

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255991/discussion-between-om222o-and-lxop).

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer @lxop, I very delighted to get this high quality answer within few mins, that to for my first question I posted after join.


I didn't know dictionary evaluates all of the operations, when we are only call for one key's value.
I used 

If you don't mind can you explain why and when all operations are called? 
-I assume its happens when dictionary is first called in very iteration, it does all the operations to complete the dictionary for fast access.
And to avoid this type of problem is it recommended to not do operational function in dictionaries?

Comment: @Saketh dictionaries are very well suited for function lookups, however, they are not lazily evaluated (all keys and values are evaluated AND created upon definition). look at the answer I provided for the correct way of using dictionaries as function pointer lookups

Comment: Can't discuss in chat (requires 20rep ) 
just adding a,b in stack.append(switcher.get(ex)(a,b)), should solve the problem @OM222O has mentioned. 
Also no need to keep stack.append(val) in calculate_value, as your doing it later in postfixExpression

Comment: Yep, there are lots of ways that you could achieve what you are trying to do. The issue with all your values being calculated first is not actually anything to do with dictionaries, it is just Python code generally. When you are setting up the dictionary, you are just giving it a value for each key, and Python is calculating each of those values just the same as if you had written `a + b` on its own

Comment: Got it! 
I thought only values of requested key is calculated. I will read more about how python runs file

Comment: Good plan. What you're thinking of is called "lazy evaluation", and while it is possible to do in Python (using `lambda`s is one common way), nothing is lazy automatically

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're actually trying to achieve but it's hard to tell since you didn't provide an example that you solved by hand or an expected output:

```
from collections import deque

switcher = {
    "+" : lambda a,b:a + b,
    "-" : lambda a,b:a - b,
    "*" : lambda a,b:a * b,
    "/" : lambda a,b:a // b,
    "^" : lambda a,b:a ** b,
}

def postfixExpression(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        print(ex, stack)
        if ex.isnumeric():
            stack.append(int(ex))
        elif ex in switcher:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            stack.append(switcher[ex](a,b))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
    return stack.pop()

expression = "2 3 7 - 7 + 9 7 2 + - * *"
print(f"\nResult {postfixExpression(expression)}")
```

Edit: Just a quick comparison between the provided solutions, here is the code:

```
from collections import deque

def postfixExpression_OP_LAMBDA(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        try:
            stack.append(int(ex))
        except ValueError:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            switcher = {
                "+" : lambda a,b: a + b,
                "-" : lambda a,b: a - b,
                "*" : lambda a,b: a * b,
                "/" : lambda a,b: int(a / b),
                "^" : lambda a,b: a ** b,
            }
            if ex not in switcher.keys():
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
            else:
                stack.append(switcher.get(ex)(a,b))
    return stack.pop()

def postfixExpression_MATCH(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        try:
            stack.append(int(ex))
        except ValueError:
            b = stack.pop()
            a = stack.pop()
            match ex:
                case "+":
                    val = a + b
                case "-":
                    val = a - b
                case "*":
                    val = a * b
                case "/":
                    val = int(a / b)
                case "^":
                    val = a ** b
                case _:
                    raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
            stack.append(val)
    return stack.pop()

switcher_ = {
    "+" : lambda a,b:a + b,
    "-" : lambda a,b:a - b,
    "*" : lambda a,b:a * b,
    "/" : lambda a,b:a // b,
    "^" : lambda a,b:a ** b,
}

def postfixExpression_OM(expression: str) -> int:
    if not expression:
        return -1
    expression_list = expression.split(" ")
    stack = deque()
    for ex in expression_list:
        if ex.isnumeric():
            stack.append(int(ex))
        elif ex in switcher_:
            stack.append(switcher_[ex](stack.pop(),stack.pop()))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong expression-> {ex}")
    return stack.pop()

expression = "2 3 7 - 7 + 9 7 2 + - * *"
```

and a quick benchmark for comparison:
[image]
My solution is 3x to 4x faster depending on what you do and uses lambdas correctly. If you rename a or b, the solution provided by @lxop will fail since he's relying on extremely poor variable scoping (more details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZE6ZWde-Os).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking the options, though one would need to have a million items in the list before even a single second difference would be seen in the runtime. More importantly though, if your bagging my answer, you should probably check that yours gives the correct answer (it doesn't)

Comment: Thankyou for this efficiency driven approach. So lambda function should be kept outside loops, such obvious thing no idea why never though of such thing.
Is it recommended to not use operational tasks in side dictionaries? I am thinking just using if-else is much better in this situation. Note: I am a very early stage in my software carrier. I am very thankful, if you can correct anything I am doing wrong

Comment: You can absolutely use lambdas inside loops, but what OM222O is showing here is a tidier way to have your code. Rather than keep all the logic that performs the operations deep inside the loop, you can pull it out as a function, and just call that function from inside the loop. That lets you give the behaviour a name and makes your loop shorter and more readable. Please don't focus on speed at this point - leave that until you actually run into a situation where the code is measurably taking too long. Otherwise you're just doing premature optimisation, which is a bad idea (google it)

Comment: @lxop I think the OP wanted inputs to be `(a,b)` while reading `b` first, whereas my code expected inputs to be `(a,b)` while reading `a` first. Updated the answer to address this